# Confusion on the sentences "It could be a done, but it is a reach"

Tags: meaning

I feel confused when reading the CNN news, please note the last sentence of below words.

"If Hillary Clinton wins nothing but the blue states on this map, she has won the election. Donald Trump has to win all the red states, all of the light red or pink states here, plus, the yellow battleground states, and he has to tip one of the light blue states in his direction if he`s going to have a chance of winning in the Electoral College. It could be a done, but it is a reach."

I have no idea the what it meant of 'It could be a done', as we know 'done' is the Past Participle of verb 'do', but here, obviously it is used as a noun. Combined the context, I am wondering if this sentence means 'it can be achieved, but it is very difficult.' Do I understand in correct way?
 And does it allow to use 'done' in this way?

I Appreciate if any guys can help to clarify.

Doris

Comment: Can you link to where you read this?

Comment: Sure, please refer to this link: http://www.tingclass.net/show-9904-377976-1.html

Comment: "THIS IS A RUSH TRANSCRIPT. THIS COPY MAY NOT BE IN ITS FINAL FORM AND MAY BE UPDATED." It looks like a mistake to me that they'll (hopefully) fix in an update.

Comment: I found it also in CNN official website : http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1610/05/sn.01.html, could you please listen this news at 03:29? I can not clarify what he said...

Comment: (Usage) *done*: achievable; *reach*: within one's limitations/abilities but not necessarily close or easy.  So to win is possible but one had to do everything one can to achieve it. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

"It is a stretch" is an idiom meaning: It would be difficult, hard to achieve, etc. The author of your quote butchered this by saying "it is a reach".

Substitute "it is a stretch" for "it is a reach" and the quote makes sense.

There is a broader lesson here: Don't assume that the people writing (or speaking) the news are necessarily using correct English. Often, they aren't.

Comment: Thanks a lot! though my question is focus on 'a done' not 'reach', thanks maybe it is oral English, or the transcript is incorrect, anyway  i was just curious before, thanks again!

Comment: It is not a butchered idiom. It is use of a similar idiomatic phrase. The indefinite article "a" before "done" should be removed.  It then becomes "It could be done, but it is a reach." and makes perfect sense.